# Informix connection string error

Tags: .net, informix

I'm trying to connecto to informix server. I've downloaded the latest CLient SDK with the server driver package, where are the .net DLL's When I'm using this connection string:

> Database=mydb;Server=myip:someport;User
>   ID=myuser;Password=mypass

I get "ERROR [08001] [IBM] SQL30081N

But when I try to add something else like protocol or the conn string from https://www.connectionstrings.com/informix/

It says that I have invalid argument exception.

I've tried to read through the stack overflow archive nothing helps, any ideas? My sdk version is: clientsdk.4.10.FC5DE.WIN

Answer (score 1):

Ok i have an answer and it's working.

First of all check if you have the right dll. I've took the dll from the wrong place. Instead of having it from the CliendSDK folder, I took it from the server package problem what is a bad idea. Second of all you have to change your solution to .net40 as it is the folder name. Then the connection string from connectinstring.com will work. Hours wasted but it was worth it I guess.

Comment: can help providing exact connection string that you had used? i am facing same issue, i had installed `Informix client sdk v4.10` but finding difficult in knowing details of connection string like what exactly should be service name and where can i find same? also other fields like port, protocol to choose etc.

Comment: I've just noticed your question. I hope it is still needed. Below is my answer how the connection string shuld look like:

Answer (score 0):

Answer for @mabiyan this is what the connection string should look like. I'm posting the answer for better readability

```xml
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="InformixDB" connectionString="Host=your_server_addres; Service=port; Server=server_name; User Id=user; Password=pass;Database=db_name;Client_Locale=your_locale;Protocol=onsoctcp;" />
```

The locale part gave me my db admin, and also thinks like port, server name and db name. Hope that helps.